# Rails 3: Escape string in the view but not all

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, view, escaping

In a view, string is escaped by default.

```
mystring = "A&B: <b>some string here</b>" 
<%=mystring%>
```

`mystring` is rendered as:

```
A&amp;B: &lt;b&gt;some string here&lt;/b&gt;
```

However, I need to have `<b></b>` tag rendered and ampersand escaped.

```
A&amp;B: <b>some string here</b>
```

`html_safe` unescapes both ampersand and `<b>` tag. Is there a way to escape special characters like ampersand but not html tags?

Comment: Why do you want to escape one, but not the other?

Comment: I have this special case where a snippet of html is returned from model and need to ensure special characters are escaped, not html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unescape specific elements using the Ruby's CGI::unescapeElement method. In your case, you would want to use the following:

```
mystring = CGI::escape_html("A&B: <b>some string here</b>")

# You can replace ["B"] with an array of tags to be escaped, i.e. ["B", "A", "IMG"]
mystring = CGI::unescapeElement(mystring, ["B"]) 

<%= mystring.html_safe %>
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html for more escaping methods.

Comment: Cheers! Be careful of the alias `CGI::unescape_element` as it only takes one argument and does not allow you to provide necessary tags.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll make a note of it. Thanks!

Comment: It looks clean, but I don't recommend this, as it unescapes the *whole attribute*. The string `<b onclick="location.href='http://myspamsite.com'" style="position:absolute;left:-2000px;right:-2000px;top:-2000px;bottom:-2000px">Hello friends!</b>` slips right into your page using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can split string on parts, then unescape some you want